# jQuery - Unchecking checkboxes that act like radio buttons

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code to make my checkboxes act like radio buttons, so that only 1 of the 3 can be checked at a time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testing input:checkbox").change(function(){
        var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked");
        this.checked = true;
    });
});
</script>
```

The checkboxes are layed out like the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="testing" name="testing" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" id="testing" name="testing" value="I">
<input type="checkbox" id="testing" name="testing" value="A">
```

This works exactly how i want it to work, not a problem, except once i click one of the 3, i cant unclick it so that none of them are checked, this is what i want to happen, so along with being only able to click one at a time, im able to uncheck them completely.

Any help would be grand :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only run the code that unchecks the others if `this` has been `checked`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Th/1/

```
$("#testing input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if( this.checked ) {
        var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").removeAttr("checked");
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's a revision that prevents the newly checked box from being unchecked when you select the boxes with the same name. It uses [`not()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude the current checkbox.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Th/2/

```
$("#testing input:checkbox").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var checkname = $(this).attr("name");
        $("input:checkbox[name='" + checkname + "']").not(this).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ is there any performance gain using the .not()? BTW Thanks, looking to implement this type of functionality here the user has a set of options but can select none or one. With using a radio I also had to create a reset button to clear it if they didn't want the option after all.

Comment: @PhillPafford: Any performance difference in either direction will be negligible, but using `.not(this)` seems more pure because you're not unchecking it, only to recheck it on the next line.

Comment: The [first one](http://jsfiddle.net/CX5Th/1/) is nice.  Being able to "clear" the choice is the use case we had for using checkboxes like radio buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Less Code! :-)

```
var boxes = $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    boxes.not(this).attr('checked', false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YqSXA/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var ischecked = $(this).attr('checked');
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    $(this).attr('checked', ischecked);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yDPhv/